# jQuery help: I can't get the result selecting the anchor link of cakephp $this->Html->link

Tags: jquery, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

```
echo $this->Html->link($val['Post']['title'],
                                    array('controller'=>'posts','action'=>'view',$val['Post']['id']),
                                    array('id'=>'rightSideLink')).'<br/>';


$("#rightSideLink").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('classTableRow');
})

$("#rightSideLink").mouseout(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('classTableRow');
})
```

It's not working.
What to do ?

Comment: Is the jQuery code inside `$( function() { ... } );`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is completely working...
you can test this code which i m providing you below....
just change controller and model as per your requirement.....

```
<?php
echo $this->Html->link($user['User']['username'],
                                    array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'view',$user['User']['id']),
                                    array('id'=>'rightSideLink')).'<br/>';
?>
<style>
.classTableRow{
    background: lime;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 30px;
}

</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#rightSideLink").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('classTableRow');
});

$("#rightSideLink").mouseout(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('classTableRow');
});
</script>
```

i checked it by myself... 
you just do one thing... just hover over #rightSideLink.....
by the way what you found not working....

Comment: i think you should use **hover()** instead of two mouseover and mouseenter methods with **toggle()** method